# May Spring MVC switch threads during a request?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, concurrency, jboss

We have a Spring MVC web application, running in JBoss, where some user information is stored in ThreadLocal objects. We have an issue where it seems that occasionally some requests will overwrite data that another request has stored in the ThreadLocal,before any of those requests have finished executing. Is this possible?

In other words, is it possible for a JBoss request to yield in favour of another request at some points, e.g. when running interceptors or accessing certain kinds of beans?

I tried reducing the amount of worker threads in JBoss to 1, and was able to reproduce our issue fairly reliably that way. This is the configuration I used:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[...] read data that another request has stored in the ThreadLocal."

I think the title of the question should be "May Spring MVC resue threads for consecutive requests", and the answer is "yes, it does all the time".

Maybe you think you clean up your threadlocal storage in every case, but there might be all kinds of exception situations in a servlet environment, some completely out of your control. For example the client may close the TCP connection at any time.

Comment: No that's not my question - I realize that consecutive requests may use the same thread. The question is if it's possible that parallell requests may use the same thread. It shouldn't be, but maybe there is some kind of common mistake that breaks the synchronization?

Comment: So where in your question is there any evidence of parallelism? One request finds data belonging to another request in threadlocal storage. You never say where in your code you populate and clear this data. Most likely consecutive requests.

Comment: Yeah sorry, now that I read back it wasn't clear that I was asking about the parallell case. Edited the OP.

Comment: And you are right - after some discussion, experiments and diving in the code we found that what was missing was cleaning up the contents of the ThreadLocal. We don't want to clean up in all cases, but the criteria for cleaning was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Occam's razor wins again :-) Sorry if I came off too harsh, I am working on that part :-)